# Should we participate in the Winter Bash?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

There is an activity in the SE network called Winter Bash, which happens on some sites. During this time, a couple of weeks, one can gain hats (like badges) and then decorate one's picture with such a hat.

We have to decide is if this site wants to participate in this event.

Even if we participate it is still possible for individual users to turn off the hats so that the page for them will look as always. However, the general impression of the site will be with hats.

Please voice your opinion either way. (In case opinions should be mixed I would propose not to participate.)

---

**Added:** At the moment there is no dissent at all, so it seems clear we participate. I will still wait two days and then communicate the result to the SE team.

Comment: Yes, we should participate. (This comment is for making a poll.)

Comment: No, we should not participate. (This comment is for making a poll.)

Comment: I am indifferent regarding our participation. (This comments is for supplementing the poll.)

Comment: On Money.SE, the OP to this question put 2 answers, a Yes and a No, and asked for voting the answers to indicate preference. Me, I thought it was fun. And it was the origin of my avatar, my dog's picture to fit the santa hat last year.

Comment: I communicated that we want to participate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My vote is a cautious yes for participation.
Those who want can ignore the hats, but if the hats motivate some people to participate more actively, the site only gains.
My only worry is that a less professional look can cause aversion, but I don't know if this is a real issue.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly. It may also be helpful for voters to see what the Winter Bash looks like. This is the first Google image that appears: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7MLht.png

Comment: Most teachers I know like a little silliness every so often. Professional schmofessional. ;)